# Dictionary size explicit initialization: pros and cons

Tags: c#, .net

Suppose we have 2 options to go:

```
public static Dictionary<TK, TV> GetDictionary(IEnumerable<TK> keys)
  {
      var result = new Dictionary<TK, TV>();
      ...
      return result;
  }
```

vs

```
public static Dictionary<TK, TV> GetDictionary(IEnumerable<TK> keys)
  {
      var result = new Dictionary<TK, TV>(keys.Count());
      ...
      return result;
  }
```

What are the pros and cons of each?
Recently in our team we had an argument.

Possible cons of explicit size

1. If number of items is small, then it makes no sense.
2. If number of items is big then Count() is expensive and leads to full enumeration of `IEnumerable`.
3. Dictionary resizing is effective and speedy - no need to optimize it.

Possible pros of explicit size

1. Precise number gains performance 'cause dictionary resizing is expensive and better avoid it.

What's the better option or is there some rule of thumb?

Comment: Any evidence it is actually making any difference in your case? I would be very surprised.

Comment: @Baldrick I'm asking about general case, so your point - it's the same and I shouldn't care, right?

Comment: General rule would be to use the simplest form first, which will almost certainly be fine. If there are performance issues from the dictionary, only then should you consider microoptimisation at that level. Incidentally in the case you mention you can convert an IEnumerable to a dictionary using linq.

Comment: Count() could be or could not be expensive: Linq is smart enough to use appropriate version of Count() for say List<> or array.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I assume general case with no optimization and non-materialized query.

Comment: the only pro you mentioned is contrary to the 3rd con ... so what is it?

Comment: @OndrejJanacek Yes it's about an argument - contrary points were mentioned and I want to know the community opinion )

Comment: You do *not* set the size, you set the *capacity*.  And Count() is not necessarily expensive, it can be O(1).  It is utterly pointless to have an argument about this, or for us to guess if you'd be ahead, you **measure** instead.

Comment: @HansPassant The dictionary will only "re-size" if you go over the capacity estimated, isn't it true? So, I'd get some time spent on `Count()`, but saved other time from avoiding re-sizing. I don't want this "go and measure" stuff, I need some theoretical basis with different aspects covered, such as some in-depth knowledge of dictionary resizing costs. I can measure concrete case, but it won't make the picture clear.

Answer (score 2):

Providing you are working with a large number of items *and* you know this number in O(1) time, I would consider providing `Dictionary` with this information. Generally, if it's cheap to precompute something, it *may* make a difference in certain scenarios.

So, in your case, if you really work with a large number of items, and are able to supply the count without actually enumerating them all (which is what the `Count()` extension method does), then go ahead. In practice, that means you should be passing *at least* an `ICollection<T>` into your method:

```
public static Dictionary<TK, TV> GetDictionary(ICollection<TK> keys)
{
    var result = new Dictionary<TK, TV>(keys.Count);
    ...
    return result;
}
```

If you *do not* know the count in O(1) time *every time* you need to construct that dictionray, then [just don't spend time optimizing something that's not causing a performance problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premature_optimization#When_to_optimize).

Comment: I wonder which are exact cases when Count gets precomputed and becomes cheap? Suppose I have a query against a list... And considering changing types from `IEnumerable` to `ICollection` - it makes question senseless as soon as main point is what's more expensive Enumeration or Dictionary resizing (and in which cases)?

Comment: Generally, `IEnumerable<T>` can provide a potentially infinite number of items (however this is a corner case, and usually it doesn't). `ICollection<T>` explicitly states that there is a known number of items in it. Every sane author of a collection class maintains the current number of items stored in it, because asking for it is a very common case. Changing from `IEnumerable<T>` to `ICollection<T>` doesn't invalidate your question. It's just a matter of efficiency and expressed expectation on the input's qualities.

Comment: I have limited knowledge about actual type that one gets after applying `Where` operator to a collection, but I doubt it has some Count property hidden within. That what makes situation different, I think.

Comment: See my updated answer. You should sort out your priorities and facts, first.

Comment: You concentrated only on `Count()` what about dictionary resizing?

Comment: Read the documentation for the `Dictionary`'s respective constructor: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tk84bxf4(v=vs.110).aspx What you pass into the construction, is the *initial* capacity. The dictionary automatically resized its internal structures when needed.

Comment: I avoid the resizing by specifying explicit capacity, am I? So, how I much I'd save vs losing on the Count() in worst case? In best case? Looks like your answer doesn't cover it

Comment: @downvoter You are welcome to indicate what you find wrong with my answer so it can be improved and made more relevant.